# Precaching with Stale While Revalidate Strategy in Workbox

Tags: javascript, service-worker, workbox, sw-precache

## Question

Is it possible to precache a file using a different strategy? i.e. *Stale While Revalidate*?

Or, should I just load the script in the DOM and then add a route for it in the worker with the correct strategy?

## Background

This is quite a weird case so I will try to explain it as best I can...

- We have two repos; *The PWA* and *The Games*
- Both are statically hosted on the same CDN
- Due to the Games repo being separate, the PWA has no access to the versioning of the game js bundles
- Therefore, the solution I have come up with is to generate an unversioned manifest (`game-manifest.js`) in the Games build
- The PWA will then precache this file, loop through it's contents, and append each entry to the existing precache manifest
- However, given the `game-manifest.js` has no revision and is not hashed, we need to apply either a *Network First*, or *Stale While Revalidate* strategy in order for the file to be updated when new versions become available

See the following code as a clearer example of what I am trying to do:

```
import { precacheAndRoute } from 'workbox-precaching';

// Load the game manifest
// THIS FILE NEEDS TO BE PRECACHED, but under the strategy
// of stale while revalidate, or network first.
importScripts('example.cdn.com/games/js/game-manifest.js');

// Something like...
self.__gameManifest.forEach(entry => {
    self.__precacheManifest.push({
        url: entry
    });
});

// Load the assets to be precached
precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest);
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, it's not possible to swap in an alternative strategy when using `workbox-precaching`. It's always going to be cache-first, with the versioning info in the precache manifest controlling how updates take place.

There's a larger discussion of the issue at https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/1767

The recommended course of action is to explicitly set up [runtime caching routes](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/route-requests) using the strategy that you'd prefer, and potentially "prime" the cache by adding entries to it in advance during the `install` step.

Comment: Thank you very much for this Jeff! I feared this would be the case, but having read through the link you posted, I now understand why. Given the unique use case I have outlined, would you be able to provide a little more guidance as to what you would do? For instance, would you have similar code to what I have posted, and then just define a runtime cache route later on? Would that even work? i.e. would it be able to recognise that `example.cdn.com/games/js/game-manifest.js` has already been loaded? Can you give an example of 'priming' the cache in the `install` step?